# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

Tags: jsf, primefaces, classcastexception, jboss6.x, jaxp

I'm trying to deploy the PrimeFaces 5.3 showcase WAR on JBoss AS 6.1.0.Final.
http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/showcase/5.3/showcase-5.3.war

I can deploy it on JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final by making the 2 changes suggested here: 
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=41278#p130047

1) Remove Listener from web.xml:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

2) Remove javax.faces-2.2.8.jar from WEB-INF/lib

But when I deploy the same modified JAR on JBoss 6.1.0.Final I get 2 Class Cast Exceptions.

I was hoping that when it worked on JBoss 7.1 I could get it going on 6.1 as they are both JEE6.

Sadly I must use JBoss 6.1 as I've a dependency on JBoss ESB.

Any advice appreciated...

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/showcase-5.3.fixed]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBo ssMojarra20ConfigureListener: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.hibernate.validator.util.LazyValidatorFactory to javax.validation.ValidatorFactory
        at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3133) [:1.7.0_67]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.attachments.helpers.AbstractAttachments.getAttachment(AbstractAttachments.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.attachments.helpers.AbstractAttachments.getAttachment(AbstractAttachments.java:56) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.mc.servlet.vdf.api.BaseAttachmentVDFConnector.lookup(BaseAttachmentVDFConnector.java:74) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mc.servlet.vdf.api.BaseAttachmentVDFConnector.getUtilityFromAttribute(BaseAttachmentVDFConnector.java:53) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mc.servlet.vdf.api.BaseAttachmentVDFConnector.getUtilityFromAttribute(BaseAttachmentVDFConnector.java:35) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mc.servlet.vdf.api.AbstractVDFConnector.getUtility(AbstractVDFConnector.java:93) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mc.servlet.vdf.api.AbstractVDFConnector.isValid(AbstractVDFConnector.java:78) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFInitializer.addBeanValidatorFactory(JBossJSFInitializer.java:65) [:1.0.3]
        at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossMojarra20ConfigureListener.doVersionSpecificInitialization(JBossMojarra20ConfigureListener.java:37) [:1.0.3]
        at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossMojarraConfigureListener.contextInitialized(JBossMojarraConfigureListener.java:56) [:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3369) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3828) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_67]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_67]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_67]
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:53) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:41) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:443) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:189) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:49) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.actions.DeploymentStartAction.doPrepare(DeploymentStartAction.java:98) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:101) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.AbstractDeployHandler.startDeployments(AbstractDeployHandler.java:168) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandlerDelegate.startDeployments(DeployHandlerDelegate.java:74) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandler.invoke(DeployHandler.java:156) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:967) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.local.LocalClientInvoker.invoke(LocalClientInvoker.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:2070) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:879) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.StreamingDeploymentTarget.invoke(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:312) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.StreamingDeploymentTarget.start(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:197) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.start(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:232) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.run(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:89) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.run(DeploymentUtils.java:155)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.deployArchive(DeploymentUtils.java:116)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.deploy.AbstractDeployer.deploy(AbstractDeployer.java:119)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.helper.CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.createContentBasedResource(CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.java:124)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.helper.CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.createResource(CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.java:56)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.ApplicationServerComponent.createResource(ApplicationServerComponent.java:304)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_67]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_67]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_67]
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.ResourceContainer$ComponentInvocationThread.call(ResourceContainer.java:525)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_67]

ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/showcase-5.3.fixed]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_67]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebXmlProcessor.getConfiguredFactory(ConfigureListener.java:852) [:2.0.3-]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebXmlProcessor.scanForFacesServlet(ConfigureListener.java:788) [:2.0.3-]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebXmlProcessor.<init>(ConfigureListener.java:745) [:2.0.3-]
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:173) [:2.0.3-]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3369) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3828) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_67]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_67]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_67]
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:53) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:41) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:443) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:189) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:49) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.actions.DeploymentStartAction.doPrepare(DeploymentStartAction.java:98) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:101) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.AbstractDeployHandler.startDeployments(AbstractDeployHandler.java:168) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandlerDelegate.startDeployments(DeployHandlerDelegate.java:74) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandler.invoke(DeployHandler.java:156) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:967) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.local.LocalClientInvoker.invoke(LocalClientInvoker.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:2070) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:879) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.StreamingDeploymentTarget.invoke(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:312) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.StreamingDeploymentTarget.start(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:197) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.start(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:232) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.run(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:89) [:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.run(DeploymentUtils.java:155)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.deployArchive(DeploymentUtils.java:116)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.deploy.AbstractDeployer.deploy(AbstractDeployer.java:119)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.helper.CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.createContentBasedResource(CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.java:124)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.helper.CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.createResource(CreateChildResourceFacetDelegate.java:56)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.ApplicationServerComponent.createResource(ApplicationServerComponent.java:304)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_67]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_67]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_67]
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.ResourceContainer$ComponentInvocationThread.call(ResourceContainer.java:525)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_67]
```

Comment: Exception suggests WAR bundles a JAXP api or impl incompatible with one provided by server. This has technically nothing to do with JSF nor configure listener itself, it just happened coincidentally exactly there because it uses JAXP to parse faces-config.xml file. You should also remove JAXP from WAR, if any.

Comment: @BalusC You were right. I removed xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar and that solved the JAXP problem, and then I removed validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar and it deployed with no problems. Now I'm getting errors about the validation but I think I can figure them out with a bit of work. Like Billy Mitchel said there's a level of difference between people and you are a Red Baron! Thanks Very Much. How do I accept you answer?

Comment: I will repost it as an answer. I initially posted it as a comment because of the ambiguity of the problem; there are more probable causes which I just wanted to exclude one by one, starting with most common one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

Normally, JAXP is already provided by a decent Java EE server (via its JRE/JDK). This exception suggests that the WAR itself incorrectly bundles an incompatible JAXP API along, overriding the server-provided one (classes in WAR have higher classloading precedence than those in server). When the code starts to actually use the JAXP implementation (which is Xerces in your specific case), it finds itself incompatible with the version of the JAXP API currently in runtime classpath and hence this exception.

When you get rid of the JAXP libraries in the WAR, then this problem shall disappear.

The Mojarra `ConfigureListener`, where all this trouble happened according to the stack trace, has got nothing to do with the concrete problem. It just coincidentally occurred for the first time there, because it needed to parse the `faces-config.xml` file using JAXP.

Comment: You were right. I removed xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar and that solved the JAXP problem, and then I removed validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar and it deployed and starts up with no problems. Now I'm getting errors about the validation but I think I can figure them out with a bit of work.

Comment: In my case, trying to migrate from JBoss 4.0.5 to JBoss 4.2.3, this message persists. I'ved remove all references to the 'xml-apis' lib but without success. What else can I do inside possible causes?